# How to run a Flask app under Google App Engine locally?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Python 3.x under GAE. Google now recommends avoiding `dev_appserver.py` and instead to call `python main.py`.

When I do this my local code modifies my GAE server datastore rather than a local version.

How do I run my Flask app locally? I want to do this so that `index.yaml` is automatically created and provide a testing environment away from test and production servers.

The reason why my code is not using a local datastore is because I'm calling

```
from google.cloud import datastore
DATASTORE_CLIENT = datastore.Client()
```

and this is auto-authenticating to my Google hosted database. How do I have locally run code use a local datastore and server-run code use my server-based datastore?

Comment: did you try the [Datastore mode Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator)?

Comment: Thanks! I’d missed this section.